# AngularsJS JavaScript Matching Words and Adding String

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a long text in `contentString`.

In `$scope.listKeyWords`, I have some keywords (car, house, red, cool)

I need to match this keywords in my text and add some stuff like:

**Input** `contentString`:

```
Hello there, I have a very nice car. It is very cool.
```

**Output expected:**

```
Hello there, I have a very nice <u>car</u>. It is very <u>cool</u>.
```

[EDITED]
[SOLUTION] thanks to @Barth Zalewski

```
for (var k = 0, word; word = $scope.listKeyWords[k]; k++) {
   var re = new RegExp(word, 'g');
   contentString = contentString.replace(re, "<u>" + word + "</u>");
}
```

How can I proceed?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: Any reason why replace() doesn't work?

Comment: Your attempt will only replace one occurance. See my answer. It should work now.

Comment: You omitted the word boundaries `\b`. Note that without them, also `car` in `care` and `scary` will be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var k = 0, word; word = $scope.listKeyWords[k]; k++) {
  contentString = contentString.replace(new RegExp("/\\b" + word + "\\b/"), "<u>" + word + "</u>");
}
```

The `\b` denotes a "word boundary" so that only whole words will be replaced.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work :( I got Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: How is your `contentString` defined? Is it NOT a property of scope? Try my edited answer. You have to replace the contentString with the correct variable name.

Comment: it is var contentArray = []; then contentString = contentArray.join("");

Comment: Nope :-( I got ReferenceError: Regexp is not defined

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. It's called RegExp (with 'E' not 'e'). Sorry for this! I have edited the answer.. Try now.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can execute and see the "word" console.log("WORD "+word); in the loop but it change nothing in contentString

Comment: contentString = contentString.replace(word, "<u>" + word + "</u>"); seems work by only change the first one, not the other. Also replaceAll doesn't work like  TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: In my example I use RegExp. There is a reason for this. With RegExp, you will replace ALL occurances, not only the first one.